# crontab script does not execute serial commands

Tags: linux, cron, debian, beagleboneblack, autostart

i am trying to get my script working, which should get executed when my Beaglebone starts.
If I execute the command in the terminal everything works fine. If I reboot the Beaglebone the script works fine too. But if I poweroff and start it again everything is working except the commands via the serial interface.

My crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin/:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/binusr/bin
@reboot /bin/bash /usr/bin/script.sh
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/binusr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyO1 raw
sleep 0.2
/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyO1 38400
sleep 0.2
echo 'ont' > /dev/ttyO1
echo "test"
exit 0
```

I have also tried rc.local but with no success

Comment: Does it work if you sleep longer?

Comment: no. If tried up to 5s sleep

Comment: probably unrelated, but why do you `export DISPLAY`? are you aware that `cron` and `rc.local` will run without an X-server?

Comment: I added `export DISPLAY` because someone wrote you should use it when you are using crontab

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are not hitting any SELinux permissions. Try taking "shields down", meaning 'setenforce 0', try again, and see if it works then. (then back to setenforce 1)

If that did the trick, with SELinux off, you'll have to engineer how to bypass certain permissions, by examining the audit log. Watch what happens to /var/log/audit/*, then read up on audit2why and audit2allow to modify specific permissions.

Comment: Is SELinux installed by default? Because I can't find anything. Also why does it work if I reboot the Beaglebone? Woudn't it block the script too, if the of permission is the problem

Comment: Yes, modern distro's install them by default. It is worth trying. Note, you can only do these instructions off you have root access. That might make the difference that you cannot see it, of you're not root when you look or setenforce

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyO1 -echo
```

Solves the problem.